# IsValid and Ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can somebody tell me the purpose of isValid in ember-data.

I am trying to use this example to display either error messages or success messages to the user:

http://grosser.it/2012/05/05/save-validation-callbacks-for-ember-dataember-js/

The problem is that when I return a 422 from the server, the code does make it back to the observers.

Also isValid is always true.

I am really struggling to get an error notification when something goes wrong.

I could use didCreate or didUpdate but this still leaves a hole in the error condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug issue that is related to this: [issue 296](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/296)

Answer (score 0):

Data validation is not currently part of ember-data although it is planned for 1.0 I believe. There are a number of issues open on GitHub related to data validation such as https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/228